Twilio conference recording also capture hold music
We are using Twilio Programmable Voice in our application. For outbound calls we are using Twilio Conference. Once the original caller dials in, we put them into a <Conference>, using <Dial> with the record attribute set. At the same time, use the REST API to make a phone call to the client which also lands them in the conference.
We have a consultancy option on the app which puts third party in the same conference. Once the agent do consultancy customer and third part went to Hold and vise versa. We use Participants resource to hold and unhold.
We have now one recording URL. Now this recording url contains hold music part which the agent did consultancy which we don't want. Is there any wait we can exclude this hold music from recording?

When you put the participant on hold also mute them using the twilio rest api. Then unmute them when you take them off hold. This should prevent the conference music from being heard on the recording.
See twilio logs on how to mute:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference-participant-resource#update-a-participant-resource
